# Non-measurable sets and sigma-algebra definition

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, terminology, lebesgue-measure

I´m starting to study about measure theory, but I have problems regarding the definition of measure space.

In my class we saw that there exists sets that are not measurable(Vitali sets in $\mathbb R$) and in order to avoid this problem we define  a sigma-algebra on a set $X$ and we call the elements of $\Sigma$ "measurable sets"

But the problem I have is that how can we guarantee that with this "definition" we cannot construct a non-measurable set. Is there a theorem that says that there can´t be non-measurable sets on a sigma-algebra over $X$ with that definition?

Or I just need to assume that we cannot find such sets over these circumstances?

Answer (score 4):

It's not that we define a $\sigma$-algebra "in order to avoid [the] problem" that non-(Lebesgue-)measurable sets exist. Rather, we define exactly what we mean by "measurable set", form the collection $\cal S$ of all such sets, and then prove that this collection *is* a $\sigma$-algebra.

Having done so, it's a triviality that every set in $\cal S$ is measurable.

Of course, there are still non-measurable sets! They're just not members of $\cal S$.

Comment: Maybe this is a silly question but can we define the concepts  of measurable set and sigma-algebra independently? I have seen in plenty of books that they first define a sigma-algebra and then they say that  a set is measurable iff is an element of the sigma algebra

Comment: The notion of $\sigma$-algebra *is* defined independently. For example, the power set of any set is a $\sigma$-algebra. It's true that the notion *is* involved in the definition of the measurable sets: they're the least $\sigma$-algebra such that blah-blah. This is not at odds with the existence of non-measurable sets! What the Vitali set shows is that the definition of measurable set isn't just trivial: the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets is not the entire powerset of the reals.